# TypeError: 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression' object is not iterable

Tags: matrix, sage

I have this 10x10 matrix, want to find the inverse matrix next. The elements are `[q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q21,q22,q23,q24,q25]`. Each element can take the value 0 or 1. The error:

```
TypeError: 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression' object is not iterable.
```

the code:

```
var('q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q21,q22,q23,q24,q25') 
(q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q21,q22,q23,q24,q25)
q11 == {0,1}, q12 == {0,1}, q13 == {0,1}, q14 == {0,1}, q15 == {0,1}, q21 == {0,1}, q22 == {0,1}, q23 == {0,1}, q24 == {0,1}, q25 == {0,1}
m=matrix(SR,10,10,[q11,q12,q13,q14,q15,q21,q22,q23,q24,q25]);
m
```

Comment: ...what language is this? You have only tagged [tag:matrix], but _many_ languages have matrices. Please read [ask]. Based on the error message I'm guessing [Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/)?

Comment: A 10 x 10 matrix should have 100 coefficients.

You only provide 10 coefficients.

Did you have in mind a 2 x 5 matrix?

In that case there is no inverse...